# video url Http error 405 can't download

Tags: android, http, http-headers, httpresponse, httpurlconnection

I have an online video url, I can use vitamio video player play it online, but once I use android HttpUrlConnection download, I failed and received http 405 error.Can anyone give me some help?

```
 HttpURLConnection conn = null;
 int totalSize = 0;
 conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
 conn.setConnectTimeout(10 * 1000);
 conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
 conn.connect();
 totalSize = conn.getContentLength();

 [1]:http://219.238.10.102/videos/v0/20140303/43/4c/69/cd1e834831bfafcdef321e0037050f45.mp4?key=9070001543d27aea&path=/data1/www&m=DC96181615C9D859EB81DA194598DF31A8A3F8DBD9CC94AB612C1489A6574E08E898F5CE76C1BA00DEEE348748C27D82DCCEF4183D058C45DD96616D9D87753F263ADF611C41D0531BA1BDCFD7DE9B16&uuid=4cc6f4b2f1d7b13fa4fd9b4233e0094fc016327ac6ddc126dc54d6f359bcca4b
```

the url is [the url of a video][1]
I put the url on http://web-sniffer.net/, it displayed right length which is 71917427.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was finally solved by add userAgent:

```
conn.setRequestProperty("User-agent", "");
```